# InvokeApiAsync<HttpResponseMessage> returns null

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Can someone explain my why that client (Xamarin.Forms PCL) call returns null?

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.MobileAppClient.InvokeApiAsync<HttpResponseMessage>("ResetTruckAuftragWorkflow");
```

> **response** is **null**. When I execute that in a console app it returns the
>   valid http response.

I use the latest stable ZUMO nugets in client and backend. There is my ZUMO backend code:

```
[Authorize]
[MobileAppController]
public class ResetTruckAuftragWorkflowController : ApiController
{
    private readonly RcsMobileContext _rcsMobileContext;
    private readonly TruckFahrerInfo _truckFahrerInfo;


    public ResetTruckAuftragWorkflowController()
    {
        _rcsMobileContext = new RcsMobileContext();
        _truckFahrerInfo = new TruckFahrerInfo(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
    }

    // POST api/ResetTruckAuftragWorkflow
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var transaction = _rcsMobileContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var truckAuftragList = _rcsMobileContext.TruckAuftrags.PerUserFilter(_truckFahrerInfo.FahrerId);
                    var truckAppIds = truckAuftragList?.Select(ta => ta.TruckAppId).ToArray();

                    if (truckAppIds != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var truckAppId in truckAppIds)
                        {
                            await _rcsMobileContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(_tawQueryTaskStatus10, truckAppId);
                            await _rcsMobileContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(_tawQueryTaskStatus5, truckAppId);
                            await _rcsMobileContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(_talQuery, truckAppId);
                            await _rcsMobileContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(_taQuery, truckAppId);
                        }
                    }

                    await _rcsMobileContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(_taQuery, _truckFahrerInfo.FahrerId);

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    return BadRequest($"Transaction failed: {e}");
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _rcsMobileContext.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

thanks

Eric

Answer (score 0):

InvokeApiAsync decodes the body that is returned and de-serializes the JSON into type T.  You should not use `HttpResponseMessage` for this purpose as it is not serializable.

If you don't care about the body, use the non-generic form of InvokeApiAsync.

Comment: Did that and response is still null: `var response = await OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.MobileAppClient.InvokeApiAsync("ResetTruckAuftragWorkflow");`

Comment: Check the response for the custom API.  If it does not return a body, you are going to get null when decoded.

Comment: Specifically, this line: `return Ok();` will return a null body, which gets translatd into a null object.

Comment: As Adrian said, Ok() function will return a null body. If you want to get some message when `PostAsync` succeed, please try to use Ok('ok').

Comment: @Jambor-MSFT There is no PostAsync! I remarked that it works when I execute it in a console application. Obviously you both cant answer that question to 100%! Again: Why the hack does it work in a console application but not in a xamarin app? Same code, different result!